# Multiple datatables in different pages in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin, datatables

I'm currently applying built-in datatables. This is my code and I want to apply this datatable to multiple tables from other view pages. I want to know how I can apply this to other tables in other view pages.

And this is my code in SampleStudentIndex as to how i call the datatables function.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#students_table').dataTable( {
        responsive: true


    } );
});

</script>



 <table class="table table-striped" id="students_table" style="font-size:14px;text-align:center;">
```

But when I apply it to ReportGenerated, datatables does not work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js"></script>


 <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#reports_table').dataTable( {
        responsive: true


    } );
});

</script>

<table class="table table-striped" id="reports_table" style="font-size:14px;text-align:center;">
```

Comment: Can you see any errors in your chrome devtools console?

Comment: @PriyankPanchal there are no errors.. maybe it has something to do with the code?

Comment: Your code looks exactly similar, if it is working for `#students_table`, it should work for `#reports_table` as well